# Django redirecting url with changed values

Tags: python, django

I have urls that take a parameter called board_slug. Before getting the template the view will replace the slug if its name is wrong and redirect it. I have already made the code for fixing the slug but do not know how insert the fixed board_slug into the new url. This code is run across multiple views so it has to work with all the following kinds urls:

```
url(r'^boards/(?P<board_slug>[^/]+)/$', views.BoardView.as_view(), name='board'),
url(r'^/front-thing/boards/(?P<board_slug>[^/]+)/new/$', views.BoardView.as_view(), name='new_board'),
url(r'^boards/(?P<board_slug>[^/]+)/etc...$', views.BoardView.as_view(), name='anything_with_board'),

class BoardView(View):
    template_name = 'forums/board.html'

    def get(self, request, board_slug):
        if wrong:
            url = get_django_url
            url.board_slug = 'new-slug'
            return redirect(url)
        else:
            return template
```

Comment: Why dont you add it as a GET parameter and you check if the parameter exists or not?

Comment: That seems like a really bad idea to me. The good news is I found a solution to my problem: return redirect(reverse(request.resolver_match.url_name, kwargs={'board_slug': board.slug}))

Comment: I dont think you can modify the slug like that. Why dont you just redirect to the next url 'boards/new-slug'?

Comment: Tested and working, looks like I can redirect/correct. Now sure what you mean by next url? what url?

Comment: If it's working its good. I mean you receive boards/bad-slug and cannot you just redirect to boards/good-slug? like redirect('boards/%s' % good-slug) without reverse, request resolver etc

Comment: @lapinkoira because this would hardcode the url and break as soon as you change your url scheme. Hardcoding urls is (rightly) considered bad practice in Django.

Comment: You are already hardcoding the url in urlpattern ;) thought it was cleaner tho, glad you found a solution!